# What's the start field mean in ffprobe output?

Tags: video, ffprobe

`ffprobe videopath` will output below info, what's the start mean here. I've searched a lot, but find nothing.

Why it's so big here, the video has only 1hour length.

`Duration: 01:00:10.01, start: 87930.830889, bitrate: 803 kb/s`

Comment: I use `ffmpeg -ss 0:01 -i in.mp4 -c copy out.mp4` to get ride of it.